# Twitter Bootstrap Typehead from textfile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use typehead in twitter bootstrap.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

If suppose i want to display elements from a specific text file. how can I do that? I am aware of basic typehead but how can I retrieve the values from a text file for typehead?

For example like:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"
       data-source='["Apples","Bananas","Cherries","Dates","Eggplants","Figs","Grapes",
       "Honeydew","Kiwi","Mango","Peaches","Plums","Raspberries","Strawberries","Watermelon","Zucchini"]'>
```

Here is my search-box code, I just want to integrate it.

```
    <br>
  <br><br><br><br><br> <br> <br> <br>
    <div class= "well">
  <center>
<div class="content-inner">
  <h1 class="pump-up">Find your Desired Course and Learn!<br> <strong>Boom, it's that easy.</strong></h1>
  <div class="full-search-bar">
    <ul class="item-stream unstyled search-input-stream">
      <li class="stream-item stream-header search-input-item">
        <form class="form-inline search-form" action="webcrawler.php" method = "post">
          <input class="xlarge" name="coursename1" type="text" placeholder="Java,Python,Ruby..You name it & We got it!" />
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" type="submit"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></button>
        </form>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any experience using Ajax or PHP?

Comment: unfortunately not. I am just a beginner trying to learn. would really appreciate help if possible.